# SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not DBNull objects

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, sqlparameter

When I add the SQL parameter `p` to the collection I get an `InvalidCastException` with the message from the post title.

`parentId` is a nullable integer and a nullable integer in the database.

Why do I get this exception and how can I solve it?

I do not use stored procedures and I have read the similar threads but they did not help me.

```
var p = new SqlParameter("ParentId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = parentId ?? (object) DBNull.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
```

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvoted. It's a well written question with code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @Thanks vcsjones for helping me :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You aren't adding your `new SqlParameter`. `p` is the result of `new SqlParameter("ParentId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = parentId ?? (object) DBNull.Value`. In other words, `p` itself is `DBNull.Value`.

Split the statement in two, like so:

```
var p = new SqlParameter("ParentId", SqlDbType.Int);
p.Value = parentId ?? (object) DBNull.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
```

Alternatively,

```
var p = new SqlParameter("ParentId", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = parentId ?? (object) DBNull.Value };
cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
```

Either would make sure `p` is the parameter, not the parameter's value.

Comment: Or you could just use parentheses: `var p = new SqlParameter("ParentId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (parentId ?? (object) DBNull)`

Comment: @phoog That would mean the same thing (well, if you add the `.Value` after `DBNull`), so still wouldn't work.

Comment: Oh yes, I see.  It must be Friday afternoon.

Comment: oh yes thank to the "var" keyword that happened also on Friday midnight here... Would I have use SqlParameter that would not have happened.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use:

```
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null
```