# "CommandText property has not been initialized" when trying to send an NVarChar Parameter as null in C#

Tags: c#, sql, nvarchar, dbnull

Why do the solutions from this question not work for nvarchar?

[SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not DBNull objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653564/sqlparametercollection-only-accepts-non-null-sqlparameter-type-objects-not-dbnu/26739678#26739678)

I always get the mentionend error, or the "SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects". CODE:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("procedure_Name", m_databaseConnection);
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter batmanParameter= new SqlParameter("@ID_Batman", "");
batmanParameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar;
batmanParameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
batmanParameter.Value = (object)DBNull.Value;

command.Parameters.Add(batmanParmater);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

ERROR:

> 2014-11-04 16:58:37,036 [1136] ERROR GothamCitySericeName -
>   TheJokerMethod - System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteNonQuery:
>   CommandText property has not been initialized at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method,
>   Boolean async) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult
>   result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)

...

Thx in advance!

Comment: User have permissions to execute procedure? How your procedure looks like? Is this copy/pasted code or you rewrote it because you adding `batmanParmater` not `batmanParameter`?

Comment: This seems weird to me. The error message talks about the CommandText property ("procedure_name" in your example) not about missing or invalid parameters. Are you sure that this is all the code involved in the problem? Do you reinitialize the command variable ? (new SqlCommand)